# getting stuck with jquery in generating list items dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var classname="";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){ 
            name=$("input#name").val();
            $("#listview").append("<li>"+name+"</li>");
            $('#listview').attr('class','item'); 
        });

        $("li.item").click(function(){
            $(li.item).removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .selected { background-color:red;width:20px;}
</style>
```

This is html code:

```
<ul  id="listview" >
   data
</ul>
```

Using above code I was able to generate unordered list items dynamically. But I was not able to add css class to dynamic list items with help of the the dynamic class(class is for

Comment: Please complete your question...

Comment: please mark one of the answers as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var classname="";    
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function(){    
     name=$("input#name").val();
     $("#listview").append("<li class='item'>"+name+"</li>");
   });

   $("li.item").click(function(){    
      $("li.item").removeClass("selected");
      $(this).addClass("selected");    
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Wont work, since click event is added before the actual <li> elements are added. You need to add the $('li.item').click() event inside the $('#submit').click() event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clickEventHandler = function(){
        //remove class from previously clicked elements.
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        //add it to the current element.
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    }       

    $("#submit").click(function(){ 
        var name=$("input#name").val(),
            ul = $("#listview");

        //generate li with jquery add a click handler to it.
        $("<li/>", {'class': "mc" })
                           .appendTo(ul)
                           .click(clickEventHandler);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I have been able to perceive from your post You can try the following code to achieve what you want

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(e){ 
           // if #submit is a submit button then You have to prevent
           // the default behavior or page will reload
           // you can do that by uncommenting following line
           // e.preventDefault();
            name=$("input#name").val();
            $("#listview").append("<li class='item'>"+name+"</li>");
        });

        $("ul#listview").on('click','li.item',function(){
            $('li.item').removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        });
    });
```

Problems with your existing code:

1. You are doing `$('#listview').attr('class','item');` which will add the class to the `ul` not the newly created `li`
2. As `li` elements has been added to DOM dynamically, simply binding `click` event with `.click()` wont work, you have to use event delegation, and [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method is recommended for doing that.
3. `$(this).addClass` will do nothing, maybe you intended to write `$(this).addClass('selected');`

Comment: thanx a lot:). i am getting it now:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the event to the dynamically created list items, not defining there click event directly using [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

```
$("li.item").bind("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(li.item).removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("otherclass");
});
```

Comment: Don't use the jQuery live() method. It is bad, and have been deprecated by jQuery. They are still supporting it, but only for backwards compatibility. Read this article for more info:  http://www.ultimatewebtips.com/why-jquery-live-is-a-bad-option-to-use/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

http://jsfiddle.net/Wd887/3/

You need to apply the click event, every time you add a new list item. Else jQuery will not liten to events on that specific item.